# Any workaround to self-referential macros in C? I'd like to append to a macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a file that uses a `FLAGS` macro from an include that I do not control. What is in `FLAGS` is not consistent. Occasionally I need to change `FLAGS` to add a flag to it. Now I know I can't do `#define FLAGS FLAGS|MY_FLAG`, but I thought if I stored `FLAGS` in a temporary variable that I could then undefine it and redefine it using the temporary and my flag. For example:

```
// Assume this next line is what's in the include file
#define FLAGS   (1|2|4)

// The rest of this is source, assume compile with -DMOD
#ifdef MOD
#define TEMP (FLAGS|8)
#undef FLAGS
#define FLAGS TEMP
#endif

int main()
{
printf("0x%x\n", FLAGS);
}
```

And if `MOD` is defined the error is `error: 'FLAGS' was not declared in this scope`. I know that I can change all the actual C code that uses `FLAGS` to instead use `FLAGS|MY_FLAG` but I was hoping to modify the macro rather than all the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something logically equivalent to `#define FLAGS FLAGS|MY_FLAG` if you define the macro as modifiable using [Boost's "evaluated slots"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/evaluated_slots.html):

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/slot/slot.hpp>

// define FLAGS as a modifiable macro and create a setter for it
#define FLAGS BOOST_PP_SLOT(1)
#define UPDATE_FLAGS BOOST_PP_ASSIGN_SLOT(1)

int main(void) {
    // set the initial value of FLAGS
    #define BOOST_PP_VALUE (1|2|4)
    #include UPDATE_FLAGS

    printf("0x%x\n", FLAGS);  // 0x7

    // update FLAGS with a new value using the old one
    #define BOOST_PP_VALUE (FLAGS|8)
    #include UPDATE_FLAGS

    printf("0x%x\n", FLAGS);  // 0xf
}
```

Despite being *witchcraft*, this is completely standard-compliant C, no extensions. Only works for integers.

(It works by taking advantage of something important: macros aren't just expanded into program code, but also need to be expanded to determine whether to follow an `#if` branch as well. Since `#if` directives are also capable of evaluating integer math, this is able to expand the actual numeric value and use it to construct a new expansion for the `PP_SLOT` that doesn't involve a reference to any macro name. This is all hidden behind the `#include UPDATE_FLAGS` directives.)

Answer (score 3):

Your only real way to do exactly what you are trying to do is to define an additional macro

```
// Assume this next line is what's in the include file
#define FLAGS_FOR_A (1|2|4)
#define FLAGS   FLAGS_FOR_A

// The rest of this is source, assume compile with -DMOD
#ifdef MOD
#undef FLAGS
#define FLAGS ( FLAGS_FOR_A | 8 )
#endif

int main()
{
    printf("0x%x\n", FLAGS);
}
```

Macros just do simple text replacement, computed before runtime

Comment: The `TEMP` macro serves no purpose. Just `#undef FLAGS` and `#define FLAGS (_FLAGS|8)`

Comment: The token `_FLAGS` is reserved to the compiler implementation. Never start a name with an underscore.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Thanks, you're right, haven't programmed in C or C++ in a while so completely forgot about that. Also thanks for helping me notice my spelling mistake by pointing this one out